# Get attributes from session calling from other war by GET (REST)

Tags: java, rest, session, get, httpurlconnection

I want to get attributes of the session of a war (War A).
This war (War A) has a REST service that return this attributes.

Then from other war (War B) I call to the service of War A.

The code of the service of War A is:

```
@Path("/emulado")
@RequestScoped
public class EmuladoRS {
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Secure
public EmuladoDTO getAtributtes(@Context HttpServletRequest         request) {
    String usuarioEmulado = "";
    String operatorId = "";

    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();

    logger.info("El SessionID es: "+sesion.getId());
    SsgUser userAuthenticated = (SsgUser)sesion.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTENAMESESSIONUSERSSG);


        usuarioEmulado = String.valueOf(userAuthenticated.getId());


        operatorId = (String)  request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTRIBUTENAMESESSIONUSEREMULATE);


    EmuladoDTO emuladoDTO = new EmuladoDTO();
    emuladoDTO.setOperatorId(operatorId);
    emuladoDTO.setUsuarioEmulado(usuarioEmulado);

    return emuladoDTO;
}
```

The call to this REST operation in war B is:

```
            String urlRestEmulado= scheme+"://"+ serverName +":" +String.valueOf(serverPort)+"/service/rs/emulado";
        URL url = new URL(urlRestEmulado); 
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID="+((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false)).getId()); 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (connection.getInputStream())));


        String output = br.readLine();
        if (output!= "null") {
            System.out.println(output);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);
            emuladoDTO = new EmuladoDTO();
            this.emuladoDTO.setOperatorId(json.getString("operatorId"));
            this.emuladoDTO.setUsuarioEmulado(json.getString("usuarioEmulado"));

            if(this.emuladoDTO.getUsuarioEmulado()!=null&&this.emuladoDTO.getUsuarioEmulado().length()>0) this.usuarioEsEmulado=true;
            else this.usuarioEsEmulado=false;
        }
```

---

Ok. The problem is that if I call to this REST operation by GET with REST Console or typing the url **in the same tab**. The operation return correct data stored in session of war A.

{"operatorId":"operador","usuarioEmulado":"587"}

---

---

But if I call by java from the war B the JSON returned have empty data (because the attributes of session are null).

{"operatorId":"","usuarioEmulado":""}

---

Why if I call from war B the attributes of session are null and if I call typing de url the attributes are well?

Help please.